# MapStruct @MappingTarget generates an empty method

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct

Have a target type, formed by Lombok:

```
@Data
@Builder
class Target {
   private final String a;
}
```

and have a DTO:

```
@Value
@Builder
class DTO {
   private final String a;
}
```

Mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface Mapper {
    void update(DTO dto, @MappingTarget Target target);
}
```

But when I compile (saw something related to JDK 11, and yes, it is 11 in my case), the compiled method is empty:

```
public void update(DTO source, Target target) {
   if (source == null) {
       return;
   }
}
```

And this is only relevant to MappingTarget. Using regular Mapping methods of 'createFromDTO' works correctly.

MapStruct 1.3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maven only uses Mapstruct processor, then you need add in Maven plugin in your pom.xml, a configuration to Mapstruct works with Lombok processor.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You don't need to include final modifier. Use @Data instead @Value as previously mentioned.

In my tests, this is sufficient to Mapstruct 1.4.1.Final works with Lombok and JDK 11.

Comment: Eventually came to similar answer (I think, a bit outdated question). But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turned to be Lombok + private final.

Mapper specifically wants Lombok's `@Data` to be stated instead of `@Value` (had thought that `@Builder` to be of use by MapStruct), and, as a result, needed to remove `final` from the fields, which were needed to be updated.

Strange thing is, this was done by "google, error and try again" (plus manually cleaning the `out` directory from the project on every attempt, since MapStruct ignored these changes), while MapStruct never gave a warning (no flags for ignoring warnings or errors were declared).

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: just as I thought. lombok and mapstruct have a rough relationship.

Comment: MapStruct doesn't care about any annotation from Lombok. It relies on the fact that Lombok properly exposes the methods. For this particular problem have a look at https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1538

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, I already have the lombok-mapstruct-binding in place, but I still had to resort to make my entity mutable by using @Data instead of @Value, as it just created the mapper bindings for explicit setters and did not use the builder after all.

This only occurred when I wanted to post-fill the entity with @MappingTarget though.